# Wpf: How to stop storyboard animation?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have an Image and I'm trying to give the user the ability to change the animation of the image from several options. The user can select a new animation but sometimes the previous selected animation won't stop and I have 2 or more storyboards running at the same time on the Image.

I have this code:

```
            private void animateZoom1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_Zoom") as Storyboard).Children[0] as DoubleAnimation);
        }


        private void animateZoom(Boolean mode)
        {
            if (mode)
            {
                effectSample.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
                effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_Zoom") as Storyboard).Children[0] as DoubleAnimation);
            }
            else
            {
                effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, null);
                cancelAnimation("LogoStoryboard_Zoom");
            }
        }

            private void animateZoom2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_Zoom") as Storyboard).Children[1] as DoubleAnimation);
        }


        private void animateOpacity(Boolean mode)
        {
            if (mode)
            {
                (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_Opacity") as Storyboard).Begin(this, true);
            }
            else
            {
                cancelAnimation("LogoStoryboard_Opacity");
            }
        }

            private void animateScaleX2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_ScaleX") as Storyboard).Children[1] as DoubleAnimation);
        }

        private void animateScaleX(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_ScaleX") as Storyboard).Children[0] as DoubleAnimation);
        }

        private void animateScaleX(Boolean mode)
        {
            if (mode)
            {
                effectSample.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
                effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, (FindResource("LogoStoryboard_ScaleX") as Storyboard).Children[0] as DoubleAnimation);
            }
            else
            {
                effectSample.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, null);
                cancelAnimation("LogoStoryboard_ScaleX");
            }
        }


        private void cancelAnimation(String storyBoardName)
        {

            (FindResource(storyBoardName) as Storyboard).Stop(this);
            (FindResource(storyBoardName) as Storyboard).Remove(this);
        }
```

and this

```
<Storyboard x:Key="LogoStoryboard_Zoom" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                By="0.5"
                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                BeginTime="0:0:0"
                Completed="animateZoom2" />
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                By="-0.5"
                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                BeginTime="0:0:0"
                Completed="animateZoom1" />
    </Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="LogoStoryboard_Opacity" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="1"
                To="0"
                Duration="0:0:8"
                BeginTime="0:0:1"/>
        <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                From="0"
                To="1"
                Duration="0:0:8"
                BeginTime="0:0:10"/>
    </Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="LogoStoryboard_ScaleX" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
            To="0.5"
            Duration="0:0:3"
            BeginTime="0:0:0"
            Completed="animateScaleX2"/>
        <DoubleAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="effectSample"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
            To="1.5"
            Duration="0:0:3"
            BeginTime="0:0:0"
            Completed="animateScaleX"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

Please help me stop the old storyboard :)

Comment: is your story board found with `FinResource` method?

Comment: yup. it is found with FindResource. I mean that it should be found...

Comment: There is only one answer for this question either it finds it or not I can't help you if I don't know the facts, one of the reasons why it might be using two animations is because it's not removing the old one This kind of information will eliminate possible causes and narrow down the possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used TryFindResource and found out that the storybaord is found, I have a Storyboard Object in my hand at that point.

Comment: Well, finally I figured out that my problem is in the repeat behavior and if repeating the animation is done by code behind then I should stop the repeat by code behind and not with the storyboard itself. I added a Boolean to stop repeating the animation when needed. This is what you get when you go from Java's world to WPF :-P